# Why does my batch script not run all commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a script for me that activates a virtual environment, install requirements and start a Python server.

My script looks like this:

```
@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d C:\Users\evaknid\venv\Scripts & activate & pip install -r reqs.txt"  

@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d C:\Users\evaknid\rm_analytics\developer-management-tool & python manage.py runserver"
```

My problem is that the script only runs the first part each time and don't go to the other one which would start the server.

What mistake have I made?

I run this on a windows 7 machine and use the cmd to run the script if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a need to create a new cmd.exe instance, or any need to join your commands on the same line:

```bat
@PushD "C:\Users\evaknid\venv\Scripts"
@Call "activate.bat"
@PIP install -r reqs.txt  
@PushD "..\..\rm_analytics\developer-management-tool"
@python manage.py runserver
@PopD
@PopD
```

The bottom two lines are probably optional, *(can be removed if you're not continuing the script beyond those commands)*.

It may not even be necessary to be jumping in and out of directories, simply using similar syntax to this, `Call "C:\Users\evaknid\venv\Scripts\activate.bat"`, may work equally as well in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

the ['cmd'](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/allhelpw2ksp4_en.php#CMD) command invokes a new command-line each time it is called. So you are basically creating two seperate instances of the commandline with these two calls.

If you call the bat file from within a fresh cmdline you dont need the cmd /k

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\Users\evaknid\venv\Scripts & activate & pip install -r reqs.txt  

cd /d C:\Users\evaknid\rm_analytics
developer-management-tool
python
manage.py
runserver
```

the /d is actually optional, since you don't change drives.
Whether you & the commands together or not is up to you.

[robvanderwoude.com](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php) is a nice resource, if you have trouble with batch file commands

Comment: Thanks for the comment and explanation. But when I try your suggestion I still get stuck after the first command. It starts the virtualenv and install the reqs, but wont cd and run server.

Comment: Well, one solution is to omit the cmd /k completely, instead opening a blank commandline and calling this batchfile from there. (I updated the answer for this)

Comment: Thanks for the help Dan. Your solution also works, but posted how I solve the problem here also.

Comment: You should mark yours as the answer then, so its closed

Comment: To low rep, so can't do that until 2 days. WIll comeback and do that

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I found a solution to my problem:

```
@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d  C:\Users\evaknid\venv\Scripts & activate & pip install -r reqs.txt & cd /d    C:\Users\evaknid\rm_analytics\developer-management-tool & python manage.py runserver"
```

The comment made by Dan help me to understand that I don't need to create two instances.